# Deciphering large program flow in Python

Tags: python, program-flow

I'm in the process of learning how a large (356-file), convoluted Python program is set up.  Besides manually reading through and parsing the code, are there any good methods for following program flow?

There are two methods which I think would be useful:

1. Something similar to Bash's "set -x"
2. Something that displays which file outputs each line of output

Are there any methods to do the above, or any other ways that you have found useful?

Comment: you can just run it through debugger in step by step mode, check out pdb http://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html

Comment: There are also some nice interactive visualizers, like [this one online](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#). Not as good as debuggers for "now that I'm at this breakpoint, let me evaluate some arbitrary expressions", but a lot better for getting a quick overview of the flow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is actually a good idea, but since I actually wrote a hook to display the file and line before each line of output to stdout, I might as well give it to you…

```
import inspect, sys

class WrapStdout(object):
    _stdout = sys.stdout
    def write(self, buf):
        frame = sys._getframe(1)
        try:
            f = inspect.getsourcefile(frame)
        except TypeError:
            f = 'unknown'
        l = frame.f_lineno
        self._stdout.write('{}:{}:{}'.format(f, l, buf))
    def flush(self):
        self._stdout.flush()

sys.stdout = WrapStdout()
```

Just save that as a module, and after you `import` it, every chunk of stdout will be prefixed with file and line number.

Of course this will get pretty ugly if:

- Anyone tries to print partial lines (using `stdout.write` directly, or `print` magic comma in 2.x, or `end=''` in 3.x).
- You mix Unicode and non-Unicode in 2.x.
- Any of the source files have long pathnames.
- etc.

But all the tricky deep-Python-magic bits are there; you can build on top of it pretty easily.

Comment: Thanks.  I ended up needing to dig through two layers of output redirection in order to insert this code where it needs to go to actually be useful =/ (every single line of output said it was coming from the same file/lineno)

Comment: @RossAiken: I probably should have explained what `_getframe` does and how I knew to use `1` there and why you might need to use `2`, and how to deal with an already-redirected stdout, etc., rather than dumping a quick hack that worked for me in one specific debugging situation and hoping you could figure it out… But it looks like I got lucky and you already knew how to deal with everything that came up, so it was useful after all.

Answer (score 1):

Could be very tedious, but using a debugger to trace the flow of execution, instruction by instruction could probably help you to some extent.

```
import pdb
pdb.set_trace()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could look for a cross reference program.  There is an old program called pyxr that does this.  The aim of cross reference is to let you know how classes refer to each other.  Some of the IDE's also do this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend running the program inside an IDE like [pydev](http://pydev.org/) or [pycharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/).  Being able to stop the program and inspect its state can be very helpful.